# How can i check if my app is running

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

1. How can i check if my android app is already running to prevent double launch?
2. How can i make "hard exit" to prevent my app running on background?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not possible to have "double launch". If you application is running already, if you try to launch another instance, than you'll resume the first launch instance.
2. You can finish activity by adding `.finish()` in all scenarios when application can be in `onPaused()` sequence of the lifecycle or add `finish()` in `onPaused()`

Comment: 2. And there is no other way to stop app, maybe like in c# Application.Exit(0);? Is there something like that?

Comment: Even If it is (like System.exit() ) it is not recommended.

Comment: This is it exactly what I'm talking about. You can also read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: This is not entirely true. I am facing this problems now. For example, if I launch my app and then make a phone call from it, the app will stay in the background (assume that I do not want to finish() it). After the call ends, my app is launched by the system (intent.action.view), but the instance, that made the phone call is still on the back stack. It was not resumed, another instance got launched... I think it is because of different intents.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
ActivityManager activityManager =(ActivityManager)gpsService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList= activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

if((serviceList.size() > 0)) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
        RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo = serviceList.get(i);
        ComponentName serviceName = serviceInfo.service;

        if(serviceName.getClassName().equals("Packagename.ActivityOrServiceName")) {
            //Your service or activity is running
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        //Close your app or service
    }
}
```

Comment: once i get which activity is running... How can i close that service which is open..