# decide if app is runnig or is not

Tags: android, receiver

I have an application in which I have a particular event receiver. My goal is to display a dialog box when the application is running, otherwise (ie if the application is not running) show a notification.

The events such as notifications or displaying dialog boxes I have implemented. I can not determine whether the user has the application on or off.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what do you mean by running? Being in the foreground - or running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfoList = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentName = runningTaskInfoList.get(0).topActivity;

String runningActivityName = componentName.getClassName();
String runningActivityPackageName = componentName.getPackageName();
```

It requires `"android.permission.GET_TASKS"` permission.

Answer (score 1):

***Exact here -***

```
ActivityManager activityManager =(ActivityManager)gpsService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> serviceList= activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

if((serviceList.size() > 0)) {
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {
        RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo = serviceList.get(i);
        ComponentName serviceName = serviceInfo.service;

        if(serviceName.getClassName().equals("Packagename.ActivityOrServiceName")) {
            //Your service or activity is running
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        //Close your app or service
    }
}
```

Source - [how-can-i-check-if-my-app-is-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858414/how-can-i-check-if-my-app-is-running).

Answer (score 1):

### application still alive or not

```
public boolean isAppRunning()
    {
        boolean appFound = false;
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningTaskInfo recentTask : recentTasks)
        {

            if (recentTask.baseActivity.getPackageName().equals("package.Name"))
            {
                appFound = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        return appFound;
    }
```

need permission also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Please check one my question is related to your question. in that please check comments.

[Check application is minimized/background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431306/check-application-is-minimized-background)

Comment: my suggestion for you is that you should maintain simple one constant variable which will gets 'true' onResume() and set value 'false' on onPause()  in baseactivity or in each activity. now you have just check constant value is 'true' that means app is foreground show dialog. and if it is 'false' that means backgroud show notification. in above code  you can just identify that app is still in background or recent activity list.